# issue with element tree not returning the correct values when parsing an xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

the program i'm having is the following.
when parsing an xml file with et that has more than 2 childs, when i'm inside of the first child gathering data it works as intended, but when i'm inside the second it takes the data of the first. but when the xml has only 1 child it works as intended.

this is the xml file i'm parsing with only 1 child

```
<exec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
 <marketstat>
  <type id="215">
   <buy>
    <volume>161730411</volume>
    <avg>1.91</avg>
    <stddev>2.09</stddev>
    <median>1.75</median>
    <percentile>2.86</percentile>
    <max>10.00</max>
    <min>1.00</min>
   </buy>
   <sell>
    <volume>62024574</volume>
    <avg>7.88</avg>
    <stddev>4.72</stddev>
    <median>6.90</median>
    <percentile>4.72</percentile>
    <max>29.00</max>
    <min>1.40</min>
   </sell>
  </type>
 </marketstat>
</exec_api>
```

this is the code i'm using atm

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from decimal import Decimal


reqs = Request('https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=215', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})


with urllib.request.urlopen(reqs) as url1:
    tree = ET.parse(url1)
    root = tree.getroot()


for type_ in root.iter('type'):
    print(type_.attrib)

    for action in root.find('./marketstat/type'):
        print("  %s" % action.tag)

        if action.tag == 'buy':

            for buy in root.find("./marketstat/type/buy"):
                print("    %s:%.2f" % (  buy.tag   ,    Decimal(  buy.text.replace(',','.')  )  ))

        if action.tag == 'sell':

            for sell in root.find("./marketstat/type/sell"):
                print("    %s:%.2f" % (  sell.tag   ,    Decimal(  sell.text.replace(',','.')  )  ))
```

and this is the output of the program

```
{'id': '215'}
  buy
    volume:161730411.00
    avg:1.91
    stddev:2.09
    median:1.75
    percentile:2.86
    max:10.00
    min:1.00
  sell
    volume:62024574.00
    avg:7.88
    stddev:4.72
    median:6.90
    percentile:4.72
    max:29.00
    min:1.40
```

what the program is doing is searching on the type tag, then buy or sell, and returning the tags and values, then when i use this xml

`reqs = Request('https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=215,216', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`
this is the only change needed to run the program with the new xml

```
<exec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
 <marketstat>
  <type id="215">
   <buy>
    <volume>161730411</volume>
    <avg>1.91</avg>
    <stddev>2.09</stddev>
    <median>1.75</median>
    <percentile>2.86</percentile>
    <max>10.00</max>
    <min>1.00</min>
   </buy>
   <sell>
    <volume>62024574</volume>
    <avg>7.88</avg>
    <stddev>4.72</stddev>
    <median>6.90</median>
    <percentile>4.72</percentile>
    <max>29.00</max>
    <min>1.40</min>
   </sell>
  </type>
 <type id="216">
   <buy>
    <volume>154135069</volume>
    <avg>1.40</avg>
    <stddev>2.53</stddev>
    <median>1.00</median>
    <percentile>3.27</percentile>
    <max>8.47</max>
    <min>1.00</min>
   </buy>
   <sell>
    <volume>21843272</volume>
    <avg>12.17</avg>
    <stddev>20.15</stddev>
    <median>8.42</median>
    <percentile>4.71</percentile>
    <max>130.00</max>
    <min>0.17</min>
   </sell>
  </type>
 </marketstat>
</exec_api>
```

this is the result of the program

```
{'id': '215'}
  buy
    volume:161730411.00
    avg:1.91
    stddev:2.09
    median:1.75
    percentile:2.86
    max:10.00
    min:1.00
  sell
    volume:62024574.00
    avg:7.88
    stddev:4.72
    median:6.90
    percentile:4.72
    max:29.00
    min:1.40
{'id': '216'}
  buy
    volume:161730411.00
    avg:1.91
    stddev:2.09
    median:1.75
    percentile:2.86
    max:10.00
    min:1.00
  sell
    volume:62024574.00
    avg:7.88
    stddev:4.72
    median:6.90
    percentile:4.72
    max:29.00
    min:1.40
```

as you can see, the results of the  transfer to , then as i increase the number of type id elements the same happens they all get the data from the first.

thanks, if you dont understand something about the code or question please let me know and ill try to awnser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from decimal import Decimal

xml = '''<exec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
 <marketstat>
  <type id="215">
   <buy>
    <volume>161730411</volume>
    <avg>1.91</avg>
    <stddev>2.09</stddev>
    <median>1.75</median>
    <percentile>2.86</percentile>
    <max>10.00</max>
    <min>1.00</min>
   </buy>
   <sell>
    <volume>62024574</volume>
    <avg>7.88</avg>
    <stddev>4.72</stddev>
    <median>6.90</median>
    <percentile>4.72</percentile>
    <max>29.00</max>
    <min>1.40</min>
   </sell>
  </type>
 <type id="216">
   <buy>
    <volume>154135069</volume>
    <avg>1.40</avg>
    <stddev>2.53</stddev>
    <median>1.00</median>
    <percentile>3.27</percentile>
    <max>8.47</max>
    <min>1.00</min>
   </buy>
   <sell>
    <volume>21843272</volume>
    <avg>12.17</avg>
    <stddev>20.15</stddev>
    <median>8.42</median>
    <percentile>4.71</percentile>
    <max>130.00</max>
    <min>0.17</min>
   </sell>
  </type>
 </marketstat>
</exec_api>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for _type in root.findall('./marketstat/type'):
  print('type: {}'.format(_type.attrib.get('id')))
  buy = _type.find('./buy')
  for prop in list(buy):
    print('{} : {}'.format(prop.tag,prop.text))
  sell = _type.find('./sell')
  for prop in list(sell):
    print('{} : {}'.format(prop.tag,prop.text))
  print('')
```

output

```
type: 215
volume : 161730411
avg : 1.91
stddev : 2.09
median : 1.75
percentile : 2.86
max : 10.00
min : 1.00
volume : 62024574
avg : 7.88
stddev : 4.72
median : 6.90
percentile : 4.72
max : 29.00
min : 1.40

type: 216
volume : 154135069
avg : 1.40
stddev : 2.53
median : 1.00
percentile : 3.27
max : 8.47
min : 1.00
volume : 21843272
avg : 12.17
stddev : 20.15
median : 8.42
percentile : 4.71
max : 130.00
min : 0.17
```

Comment: when i try to run the code it doesnt run, this is the output `{'id': '215'}
  buy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/fjasis/Desktop/xml_data_import.py", line 20, in <module>
    for buy in action.find("./marketstat/type/buy"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: Thanks for the solution,  could you tell me the process of the fix? For future reference and implementation, thanks once again

Comment: Thanks for the solution,  could you tell me the process of the fix? For future reference and implementation, thanks once again

Comment: Sure. We first find all `type` elements. We know that for such element there is 1 buy element and 1 sell element. So we loop over the types and for each one we find the sell & buy. Once we have them - we print their children. Feel free to vote up if my answer helped you.

Comment: thanks, i voted up, but since i'm new to stack overflow it didnt registered on the awnser, also market it a good awnser, thanks again, could i contact you in the future if i need some python related help?

Comment: `could i contact you in the future if i need some python related help` -- this is not the way it works in stackoverflow ... You ask a question and (if it is a good one) - you will get an answer from someone.

Comment: Last question, if I needed to find just one value using the code you gave me earlier, what would I need to change so it works?

Comment: Look at ElementTree python docs. See the difference between find and findall